# Is there anyway to bypass 'Unknown sources' setting without having the application actually downloadable in the market?

Tags: android

Is there anyway to bypass 'Unknown sources' setting without having the application actually downloadable in the market? Signing up for the market is fine but I do not want the application actually available via the market due to partner restrictions. However, installation should be smooth without requiring the user to allow installation of application from non-market applications.

Comment: "However, installation should be smooth without requiring the user to allow installation of application from non-market applications." Don’t you think that this sentence is a bit self-contradictory?

Comment: He's not been online for nearly a a year; I'm not so sure you'll get an answer...

Answer (score 1):

No.  The whole point of the "unknown sources" setting is to explicitly prevent what you're trying to do.

(Or at the very least, I truly hope there is no way to bypass that setting.  It's a security setting users configure to prevent unwanted apps from being able to install on their phone.)

Answer (score 0):

You can ask your users to install Java, Eclipse and ADT, gives them the source code and tell them to install the app with Eclipse.
I think you don’t need the "Unknown Sources" setting for that.

(half joking, this *is* a way to bypass this setting)